# Natron node reroute

Tags: video-editor, connectors

In Natron, is there a reroute node to split connection into two nodes? Blender has this feature. It is called reroute node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

Hold Ctrl and yellow points will appear in the middle of connections.
Click on one where you would like to create the reroute.

You can now move it around and connect nodes to it.

This apparently works on "arrow connections" only, which makes sense.

You can also use the left toolbar (or throught a node - right click) and under "Other", you can find the "Dot" node.
Thus, in Natron it's called "Dot".